# Connect to Mysql from internet works, but when i try from mysql query browser it's failed (Err. 2003)

Tags: mysql, localhost

i can connect to mysql-phpmyadmin throught internet from browser(i.e google chrom), 
but when i try it from mysql query browser it's always failed. It's always show error 2003.

i already created inbound rule to allow port 3306.
And installed ODBC Driver Connector ver 5.2.6.
I can connect to mysql from LAN, but somehow, i can not connect from Internet.
There is a different version mysql-phpmyadmin from LAN and Internet :

From LAN : MySQL

> Server: localhost via TCP/IP
>
> Server version: 5.5.16

From Internet

> Database server
>
> ```
> Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
> Server type: MySQL
> Server version: 5.1.73-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPLv2)
> ```

Is it the problem (The difference ver.) ? Should i install ODBC Connector ver 5.1.73 ? please help me to solve this problem

Thanks,

Comment: Error 2003 is not enough information.  There should be a number in parentheses after the error message, that can be interpreted to more precisely pinpoint the issue.  Also, I don't know where you're getting the information about the server running 5.1.73, because you are clearly not connecting to that server via the Internet -- impossible, because unix sockets are only accessible when you are connecting to a server from the same machine where the server is running.

Answer (score 1):

You're clearly running two versions of mysqlserver.  I bet you have one with networking disabled, and that's the one that phpMyadmin is getting at.  Localhost via unix socket is not the same as localhost via 127.0.0.1.  You often need to take that into consideration with your grants as well.

But to be perfectly clear, I have no idea why you'd want two version of mysql running on your box if you don't seem to be aware of it.  I'd kill one.

Answer (score 0):

if that is not an issue with permissions, then, please check the user you are trying to connect to the database has localhost permissions. I mean, it is not the same to GRANT permissions in MySQL to a user as user@33.44.55.66, that to GRANT him permissions as user@localhost.

So, open MySQL using phpMyAdmin, and be sure you are GRANTing the user permissions to connect through localhost to the database.

Hope that helps,

Comment: The error number is 2003, (From my experience) the problem is about ODBC Connector / Forwared Port / Wrong Host name or IP.
Grant permissions is on another error no.
Anyway, thx for the answer,,